# how to animate activity from center of screen and then spread to full screen

Tags: android

I want to Animate the activty from the center of screen then open full screen . (Like a flower opening).

I have tried this but it slides in.
Start

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

End

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

```java
Intent detail = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
startActivity(detail);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.start,R.anim.end);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ICS, default opening animation is scaling up, which you want. I got these code from ICS resource directory. you can find another examples from your platform files( android-sdk-macosx\platforms\android-15\data\res\anim\activity_*.xml)

I got below code from `activity_open_enter.xml`.

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:zAdjustment="top" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_cubic"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <scale
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.1"
        android:fromYScale="1.1"
        android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: what is @interpolator/decelerate_cubic and @interpolator/decelerate_quint, where can I find it.

Comment: It's platform resource. You can find it https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/interpolator/decelerate_quint.xml and https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/interpolator/decelerate_cubic.xml

Comment: I got the error "no resource found that matchesthe given name @interpolator/decelerate_quint", how can I do?

Comment: @naiyu You should check the number of sdk version that decelerate_quiit is added. If your minSdk level is below that, you should define different activity_open_enter.xml which uses interpolator that older sdk provides.

Comment: I have use @android:interpolator instead of @interpolator/